# How do you configure X11 forwarding over SSH on AIX?

Tags: linux, ssh, unix, aix, x11

Here is what I've tried.

I've edited /etc/ssh/sshd_config on the remote AIX system

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost yes
```

as well as set $DISPLAY

```
DISPLAY=localhost:10.0
export DISPLAY
```

...reboot

connect via RHEL

```
ssh -X me@hostname
```

run xclock

```
xclock
```

get the following output:

```
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X connection to localhost:10.0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown)
```

also `xauth list` doesn't print anything.

Comment: Does `xauth list` print anything before you run the `ssh` command?

Comment: on the RHEL machine?

Comment: Worth mentioning you need to be in a X-windows environment on the client side in order for this to work.

Comment: Just a comment: avoid it. It is not only slow but also fragile. I would go with Xvnc or any of the recent low-bandwidth and mobile terminal server protocols. Compression is better and re-attaching is just a priceless stability feature.

Comment: Can you start clients in the local shell session before you start SSH? It should print a xauth token and display should be set

Answer (score 2):

```
DISPLAY=localhost:10.0
export DISPLAY
```

I presume this is in your shell startup files (`.bash_profile` or similar)? Try removing it. `ssh -X` automatically sets this variable for sessions where it's forwarding X. It shouldn't be necessary for you to set this variable manually, and you may be setting it to the wrong value.

By way of background, the default TCP port for X is 6000, corresponding to "localhost:0.0". `ssh -X` normally starts with port 6010, which corresponds to "localhost:10.0", and works upwards until it finds a free port. If port 6010 was in use, then it might bind to 6011 and set DISPLAY to "localhost:11.0". This is why you should let `ssh` set DISPLAY for you.

Comment: It still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

you must ensure your AIX server's  windows manager is working . for example, if you use CDE , please use **netstat -an|grep 177** to check 177 port is listening.

Then you can type **xhost +** to disable access control.

At last , try to use Xmanager to login, both xstart and xbrowser are ok. if you use xstart , you should run **Xmanager-passive** first, then choose the command as **CDE**.  if you use xbrowser, you can choose **Secure XDMCP** as login method.

Comment: Turning off security is very risky